# PHP Login redirect

Tags: php, authentication

I'm building a page and have a problem. Problem is next:

I have index.php that contains include 'header.php' and 'footer.php'.

In header.php I have a form with username and password fields and that form have submit with name login_form.  The code in header.php is next:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'functions.php';
if (isset($_POST['login_form'])) {

    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $password = $_SESSION['password'];

        if (!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {

            connectDB();

   $sql="SELECT id, name, type FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password ='$password'";
   $result = mysql_query($sql);

   if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0 ) {
                $error = "No user with that combination username and password! ";
                echo $error;
                header("Location:index.php");
            } else {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                echo "Some message " . $username;
                header("Location:index.php");
        }    }
```

I spent two days and I'm so confused because I know that solution is simple but I can't reach it.

I want that when I login, corresponding to user type (admin, regular user and guest) to show  me the index page with appropriate menu for each user on index.php.
I know that I need some stat variable so when that variable is set to for example 1: shows me admin submenu and when it is 2 shows me for regular user. So please can you help with that. here is link to my page, how it look likes. [enter link description here](http://lab.b3nky.com)

Comment: So after login, you can put a variable with admin,guest,user. Then check if the user is logged in and which session variable he has. Then use if else clause with php include. So they will always see the correct site. `$_SESSION['type'] = "admin";`

Comment: mysql functions have been deprecated. Use PDO or mysqli instead!

Comment: yes, I know that they are deprecated but building this for college, so I must use old way.

Comment: Have a look at what I posted below. @b3nky

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT

This `mysqli_*` based method worked for me, which already resembles one of my scripts.

**N.B.:** I commented out the `header` for testing purposes as well as a line of code that threw an error.

***Sidenote:*** I know it's a college project, but storing passwords in plain text is insecure. Just a quick FYI.

```
<?php
session_start();
// include 'functions.php';

$link = new mysqli("localhost","xxx", "xxx", "xxx");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

if (isset($_POST['login_form'])) { // is my submit button name below in form

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['password']);

    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $password = $_SESSION['password'];

        if (!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {

   $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password ='$password'";

   $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

// throws an error
//   if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0 ) {

// works properly
   if(mysqli_num_rows($result) !=1 ) {
                $error = "No user with that combination username and password! ";
                echo $error;
                // header("Location:index.php");
            } else {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                echo "Some message " . $username;
                // header("Location:index.php");
        }

    }

}

?>

<form action="" method="post">
Username: 
<input type="text" name="username">
<br>
Password: 
<input type="text" name="password">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="login_form" value="Submit">
</form>
```

---

### Original answer

You have a quote missing in `password =$password'` and hoping it's not a typo.

Rewrite:

```
$sql="SELECT id, name, type FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password ='$password'";
```

Plus a missing closing brace `}` for your `if (isset($_POST['login_form'])) {`conditional statement.

---

Or, you may need to use `SELECT *` if the above still did not work with the fixed missing quote.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password ='$password'";
```

Comment: yes, I know that they are deprecated but building this for college, so I must use old way. About a quote I don't have typo in origin.

Comment: I just edited my answer a minute ago. Your posted code has a missing closing brace `}` for your `if (isset($_POST['login_form'])) {` conditional statement. @b3nky

Comment: Also, I just tested your code with my own info, and it threw an error when I did `SELECT id, name, type FROM users` but worked if I did `SELECT * FROM users` @b3nky so that could be the problem. Try it that way instead.

Comment: Also, instead of doing `if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0 )` you may want to change that to `if(mysql_num_rows($result) !=1 )` since the first method did not work properly. @b3nky

Comment: I made an **EDIT** with a `mysqli_*` based version, which works (based on what I use, which resembles your code). @b3nky You just need to replace the DB credentials to your own. Plus, `$link` in the code is based on DB connection, so if your DB variable is different, you will need to change those.

Answer (score 0):

...I made it. And here is how:

When user log in, because every user have his type (admin, user, moderator) I wanted to show him menu for him.

When authentication is done ->

user_type = 0 is admin

user_type = 1 is user

header.php

```
 <?php
 ...
 if(isset($user)) {
  if $user_type == 0} { ?>
    <ul class='submenu'>
                <li><a href='skladiste.php?dnr=3'>Add new item</a> |</li>
                <li><a href='skladiste.php?s=6'>Promet robe</a> |</li>
                <li><a href='admin.php?pregled'>Edit users</a></li>
            </ul><?php } 
    else if ($user_type == 1) { //Menu for user  ?>
            <ul class='submenu'>
                    <li><a href='naruci.php'>Order item</a> |</li>
                    <li><a href='kosarica.php'>My orders</a> |</li>                     
                    <li><a href='artikli.php?stanje'>Edit my profile</a></li>
                </ul>
            <?php }} ?>
```

Comment: just wondering which way is better to echo a menu? like this above or trough echo "<ul class='some_name'</ul><li><a href='#'>Link</a></li>...and so on"; ?